# How should one start with ffmpeg's API?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to make a real time streaming program that takes input from a webcamera, ffmpeg looks like a good library for encoding a stream of images but there is no documentation or community tutorials (there is just a doxygen API reference).Where should I start if there's no official documentation?

Comment: this site gives a good start http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/  Although this site is information is outdated, it gives a good starting point.

Comment: follow this simple application [C++ - Ubuntu] which is easy to understand https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp

Comment: some useful links 1. https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial 2. https://www.amazon.com/dp/1479327832/?tag=stackoverflow17-20 3. http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html